# Process response data into Struc

Tags: json, go

I am new to GO and I am working through a problem I can't seem to wrap my mind around:

I am making a GET request against a target and getting back a JSON response similar to below:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "def":{
            "key":[
               {
                  "id":84,
                  "name":"T1"
               },
               {
                  "id":19,
                  "name":"T2"
               }
            ]
         },
         "id":2,
         "Name":"Test 1"
      },
      {
         "def":{
            "key":[
               {
                  "id":14,
                  "name":"T3"
               },
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"T4"
               }
            ]
         },
         "id":3,
         "Name":"Test 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I take this `resp.Body` and save it in a manner where I can start working with the data?

In Python I could easily do something like `data = resp.json()['data']`.

Would I do something like this into a Definition struct?

```
var output Definitions 
json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp.Body), &output)
```

Comment: Here is an [example](https://gobyexample.com/json)

Comment: Also [JSON-2-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) is handy for converting large JSON schema and turning it into a compatible Go struct to use against `json.Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not recommended, you can [unmarshal arbitrary JSON data](https://blog.golang.org/json) into an `interface{}` and then assert that to a `map[string]interface{}`:

```golang
func main() {
    input := []byte(inputJSON)
    var f interface{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal(input, &f)
    JSONmap := f.(map[string]interface{})

    fmt.Println(JSONmap["data"])
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ go run main.go
[map[Name:Test 1 def:map[key:[map[id:84 name:T1] map[id:19 name:T2]]] id:2] map[Name:Test 2 def:map[key:[map[id:14 name:T3] map[id:2 name:T4]]] id:3]]
```

You can find a live example here: https://play.golang.org/p/vg-9_KgfJXx